# Dependent Picklists - StyleClass attribute doesn't work

Tags: visualforce, dependent-picklist

**Situation**

I've implemented a dependent and a controlling picklist field.

```
<apex:inputField value="control__c" styleClass="abc" />
<apex:inputField value="dependent__c" styleClass="def" />
```

**Issue**

The style class "def" doesn't appear in the resulting html code:

```
<span>
    <select id="j_id0:j_id14" name="j_id0:j_id14" disabled="" >
        <option value="__">--None--</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="j_id0:j_id14 value="__">
</span>
```

Answer (score 5):

I can demonstrate that there is a bug in Visualforce's handling of dependent picklists where all of the following attributes are not rendered properly and do not work:

- onblur
- onchange
- onclick
- ondblclick
- onfocus
- onkeydown
- onkeypress
- onkeyup
- onmousedown
- onmousemove
- onmouseout
- onmouseover
- onmouseup
- onselect
- style
- styleClass
- all HTML pass-through attributes

If you create an `<apex:inputField>` containing any of these attributes, they are not displayed in your visualforce page when it is loaded.

I'm in the process of filing a bug report and hoping that SFDC will be responsive!

In the meantime, I recommend using [mast0r's solution](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/46880/63).

Comment: Did you ever file a bug report for this?

Comment: Yes. Still working my way through the endless escalation of Salesforce support...

Comment: SFDC reports that this error will be fixed with this known issue: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T4jMAAS

Answer (score 2):

Really strange behavior.

It seems that SF [recognizes](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_inputField.htm) this issue:

> The CSS style class used to display the inputField component. **This**
>   **attribute may not work for all values.** If your text requires a class
>   name, use a wrapping span tag.

As workaround you can wrap your lists with some DIV and assign a style class to this element:

```
<style>
    .myStyle select{
        color:red;
    }
</style>

<div class="myStyle">
    <apex:inputField value="{!test1obj.DependenList1__c}" id="list1"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!test1obj.DependenList2__c}" id="list2"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [**HTML pass-through attributes**](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_html_features_pass_through_attributes.htm), as they are supported by the [**inputField**](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_inputField.htm) component.

```
<apex:inputField value="control__c" html-class="abc" />
<apex:inputField value="dependent__c" html-class="def" />
```

---

**Update:**

In case the class attribute is still not rendered, you could do a workaround by using some custom attributes set via HTML pass-through attributes, and styling the elements with CSS selectors targeting the custom attributes:

```
<style type="text/css">
input[data-cssclass=abc] { color:red; }
input[data-cssclass=def] { color:blue; }
</style>
<apex:inputField value="control__c" html-data-cssclass="abc" />
<apex:inputField value="dependent__c" html-data-cssclass="def" />
```

Comment: sounds like a solution but isn't one. I tried it and the "html-class" attribute doesn't work.

Comment: updated my answer with a potential alternative

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But no "html-" attribute works.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to use `apex:pageBlockSectionItem` with a `dataStyleClass` attribute.

Below I show example of simple visualforce markup and what the generated HTML looks like. Knowing the HTML structure we can devise appropriate CSS selectors to apply our own styling or for using jQuery to get the value, etc.

## Visualforce Markup

```
<apex:inputField value="{!myObj.controllingPicklist__c}"/>

<apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyleClass="foo">
    <apex:outputLabel value="Dependent Picklist"/>
    <apex:inputField value="{!myObj.dependentPicklist__c}" required="true"/>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

## Generated HTML Markup

```
<!--
    one of the two <td> blocks will be generated
    depending on if required="true" attribute is used
 -->

<!-- if required="true" -->
<td class="dataCol foo">
    <div class="requiredInput">
        <div class="requiredBlock"></div>
        <span>
            <select id="j_id0" name="j_id0">
                <option value="Red">Red</option>
                <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
            </select>
        </span>
    </div>
</td>

<!-- if required="false" -->
<td class="dataCol foo">
    <span>
        <select id="j_id0" name="j_id0">
            <option value="Red">Red</option>
            <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
        </select>
    </span>
</td>
```

Regardless if `required` attribute used or not, the CSS selector is simply:

## CSS Styling

```
<style>
    .foo select {
        /* apply styling to the select input */
    }
</style>
```